# How to import config network outputs for each ip in a csv format using ansible?

Tags: python, csv, ansible

I need to know how to print network ipv6 address in a csv format using ansible and python. I am using vscode to run the playbook.

This the output after running task: task memory 
            ok[ip address]->{msg: "hostname, ip, 153.2.242.166"}
this the code

```
---
-hosts: all
 tasks: 
  - name: ports
    command: "grep net. ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports /etc/systc1. conf"
    register: grep_output
    - name: ram 
      debug:
        msg:"{{inventory_hostname_short}}, memory{{ansible_memory_mb['real']['total'}}"
```

Comment: Do you have some code that you have written?

Comment: Yes,@RHP 12.  I do have.

Comment: is a shell command?

Comment: it has command module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just export collected data to json and then transform entire set with tabulate module. Or fill sqlite db with values and export data to csv. I use line in file module.